# How to append the the response of new API hit in previous dataset of RecyclerView while implementing pagination

Tags: android, pagination, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement the pagination in recyclerView, And I want to append the response of new API hit with the previous dataset. 
How should I do that ? 
All of the answers that I have seen clears the previous ArrayList and then add the new data to it. But i want to retain the old data.

for scrolling i have done this :

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
            {
                if(dy > 0) //check for scroll down
                {
                    visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                    totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                    pastVisiblesItems =((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                    if (loading)
                    {
                        if ( (visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount)
                        {
                            ++PAGE_NUMBER;


                            loading = false;
                            getListViaDistance(latitude, longtitude,PAGE_NUMBER);
                            vetAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

After you get new **list of records** add them to the **arrayList** you have passed to **recycleview adapter** and call **notifyDataSetChange** on your **adapter** object. 
Suppose arrayList1 is your arrayList which you have passed into your adapter. Now, when you get your items second time, you created one new arrayList say arrayList2. After that do like this

```
arrayList1.addAll(arrayList2);
adapter.notifyDataSetChange();
```

Comment: that is my question . 
let me explain my full scenario: 
I am getting my response in String, which is an object of single key value(arrayList) pair. when I scroll down and make another hit I receive the response in String again , I parsed arrayList into JSONArray . Now I have to  append this arrayList into previous arrayList

Comment: Edited my answer, plz go through this.

Comment: I have made a global arrayList , and i add each response in that and then passing it into the adapter constructor .

  adapterDataset.addAll(petSListResponse.servicelist);
 vetAdapter = new PetServiceListAdapter(mActivity, adapterDataset, Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longtitude), sTitle);

Whenever end is reached a function is called and its response is passed to a function in which it is added to **adapterDataset**. 
But the problem is each time **vetAdapter** is initializing because of which recyclerview scrolls to top .

Comment: you have to call **vetAdapter = new PetServiceListAdapter(mActivity, adapterDataset, Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longtitude), sTitle);** only once (at the starting) and at the scroll end you have to **addAll** response item in global arrayList and have to call **vatAdapter.notifyDataSetChange();**.